# how to add syntax highlights in gedit in x2go Redhat 6.5

Tags: linux, syntax-highlighting, gedit

I am trying to add source highlights to gedit 2.28.4 
I created neuron.lang and neuron.lang. 
I put them in the following directories,

```
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs
```

but still I can not see the syntax highlights

Any suggestions?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had a mistake.. When copying the xml data.. It added a tab.
Anyway. The way that I found what is the problem ( and this is why I do not delete my post)
Is to go to terminal and then ( when all other gedit are closed)

```
gedit --g-fatal-warnings
```

It will tell you what are the errors.